# javascript hide code for secret keys etc

Tags: javascript, api, secret-key

I am using the Ribbit javascript api and trying to figure out how not to show the secrety key and all those application settings which are set in a code block using a Ribit.init function:

Ribbit.init("consumerKey");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. All JS is public viewable.

Unless you want to base64 encode the key on the server side and modify the init function to decode it first thing. It's easily reversible, but it will obfuscate it a bit.

Comment: cool are there any work arounds for having such information publically available. I'm guessing this happens in a few javascript apis although I have not used many.